# printing win / loss results in my guessing game

Tags: python

Hi all programming masters! Im working on a python guessing game and want to change the format of my print to file from "name: win 0: loss 0: guess 0", to "Name | Win or loss (not both) | number of guesses".  Im not sure how to make it print the win OR loss, do i need another if statement to print to the txt file?

```
import random

print("Number guessing game")

name = input("Hello, please input your name: ")
win = 0
loss = 0
guesses = 0

diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6)

if diceRoll == 1:
    print("You have 1 guess.")
if diceRoll == 2:
    print("You have 2 guesses.")
if diceRoll == 3:
    print("You have 3 guesses.")
if diceRoll == 4:
    print("You have 4 guesses.")
if diceRoll == 5:
    print("You have 5 guesses.")
if diceRoll == 6:
    print("You have 6 guesses.")
elif diceRoll != 1 and diceRoll != 2 and diceRoll != 3 and diceRoll != 4 and diceRoll != 5 and 
diceRoll != 6:
    print("Invalid input!")



number = random.randint(1, 3)

chances = 0

print("Guess a number between 1 and 100:")


while chances < diceRoll:


guess = int(input())

if guess == number:

    print("Congratulation YOU WON!!!")
    win += 1
    guesses = guesses + 1
    break
elif guess < number:
    print("Your guess was too low")
    guesses = guesses + 1
else:
    print("Your guess was too high")
    guesses = guesses + 1
chances += 1

else:
    print("YOU LOSE!!! The number is", number)
    loss += 1

print(name)
print("win: "+str(win))
print("loss: "+str(loss))


stat = open("Statistics.txt", "a")
stat.write(name + ":" + " win: "+str(win) + " loss: " +str(loss) +" guesses: "+str(guesses)),
stat.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the critical part using the ternary statement, an "if-then-else" *expression*, like this:

```
result = "Win" if win == 1 else "Loss"
stat.write((name + ":" + result + " guesses: "+str(guesses))
```

Beyond this, I strongly recommend that you look up "Python output format", so you can improve your range of expression.  You won't have to keep doing string construction for your output statements.

Comment: Thanks for the help / advice, i'm really new to any sort of programming and will check it out for sure!

Comment: "Really new" suggests that you should review the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting questions; you don't want to get down-voted for being off-topic.